# Display Child field at vfp from Controller

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, soql

I'm trying to display subqueries columns on my Visualforce page but I can't.

Apex controller:

```
public class FormController {

    private final FormularioDeVisita__c formulario;

    public FormularioVisitaPdfController() {
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null){
        formulario = [
        SELECT 
          ChequeEmpresa__c, SedePropria__c, CNPJ__c, MercadoExternoCliente__c, DataFundacao__c,
          (SELECT 
                FormInfoPercent__c, FormInfoText__c, FormInfoCheckbox__c, FormInfoDate__c, FormInfoCurrency__c,
                FormInfoPercentDecimal__c, FormularioVisita__c
            from FormularioVisitaChild__r) 
        from FormularioDeVisita__c 
        WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        }
    }

    public FormularioDeVisita__c getformularioVisita() {
            return formulario;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update formulario;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example from Visualforce page:

```
  <tr>
     <td class="table td">Mercado livre?</td>
     <td class="table td_right">{!formularioVisita.MercadoLivre__c}</td>
  </tr>
```

Using like that I can display the columns from the father without problems, but when I try to display from children, I can't.

I didn't find any information about it.

Display children columns in my HTML in Visualforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `<apex:repeat>`, `<apex:datatable>`, `<apex:pageBlockTable>` tags.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm contains example of using repeat to access `Account.Cases`. In your code it'll be repeat over `{!formularioVisita.FormularioVisitaChild__r}`

Comment: Cool, thats what exactly what im looking for.
Thanks for the help!